# "At the end of the day..." と同意の日本語表現はありますか？

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, phrase-requests

例えば、"At the end of the day, what do you work for?" と日本語で言いたい場合、下記の空白はどんな表現で埋めますか？

> "______、何のために働くのでしょうか？"

「結局」だと思うのですが、違いますか。

Comment: 「最終的に」ではありませんか？

Answer (score 6):

結局 works, but it's used primarily in the sense of "in the end" to describe what happened last, as in "結局電車に乗れなかった". In your context, you are seeking a decisive and/or fundamental argument rather than random thoughts. In such cases, better and unambiguous options include:

- 結局のところ
- つまるところ
- とどのつまり
- なんだかんだ(言っても)
- なんやかんや(言っても)

Comment: Is 要するに another option?

Comment: @Earthliŋ It's like "In short", but it's not really the same as "At the end of the day".